# Send html data with json including onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, json, codeigniter, datatable

I'm using [datatable](https://datatables.net/) and want to refresh table using ajax.reload().
For that, i need to send all table with json statement.
my code is this:

```
function relaod_table(){
        $data = $this->admin_model->get_user();     
        for ($i=0; $i < count($data) ; $i++) {
            $more = '<button type="button" id="'.$data[$i]['user_id'].'">test</button>';
            $data[$i]['more'] = $more;
        }
        echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
}
```

The received data is correct and each button has the id which is the user_id.
The problem is when i call the id, It doesn't triggers and nothing happen.

```
$( "#234" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

My questions are

1: how can i trigger the button's by id?

2: If i wanna use onclick() function for the buttons, when i send the json, i get the error that says Call to undefined function delete_user(). Can i use onclick in this situation?

```
$more =  '<button type="button" id="'.$data[$i]['user_id'].'" onclick="'.delete_user().'">test</button>';
```

3: How can i trigger the button i click on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why use `user_id` as an `id` attribute? id cant start with number.

Comment: I changed it to bt.id that make it for example "bt234" but nothing chsnged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
$('table').on('click', '#234', function() { 
        code here 
});
```

But call this with class and use data-* parameter to get user_id.
Hope this helps you